# Show Arabic on Aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, encoding

I am getting Arabic text from xml to string. I need now to print this string to Aspx page.

I debugged the application and the same encoded string was printed on my aspx page. This is how it looked like

```
string abc="â€«Ø´Ø§ÛØ±Ø§Û ÙÛŒØµÙ„â€¬â€Ž";
```

String result contains xml.

This is how I am reading xml:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument {InnerXml = result};
var directionsResponseNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("DirectionsResponse");
var routes = directionsResponseNode.SelectNodes("route"); 
foreach (XmlNode route in routes)
 {
    string abc=route.SelectSingleNode("summary").InnerText;//Here I am reading arabic
 }
```

How can I show it as Arabic on aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably reading your XML file with the wrong encoding. Make sure you're using the write encoding. It can be UTF-8 or code page 1256 (`Encoding.GetEncoding(1256)`)